# ADB Install Fails With INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I am having issues installing an apk to my device.

```
adb install <.apk>
```

Using the above command returns the following:

```
5413 KB/s (99747 bytes in 0.017s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]
```

Any idea on what might cause this issue?

It definitely recognizes the device.  Could it be an issue with the apk?

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Looks like you need to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml`
Change `android:testOnly="true"` to `android:testOnly="false"` or remove this attribute.

If you want to keep the attribute `android:testOnly` as `true` you can use `pm install` command with `-t` option, **but** you may need to `push` the apk to device first.

```
$ adb push bin/hello.apk /tmp/
5210 KB/s (825660 bytes in 0.154s)

$ adb shell pm install /tmp/hello.apk 
    pkg: /tmp/hello.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]

$ adb shell pm install -t /tmp/hello.apk 
    pkg: /tmp/hello.apk
Success
```

I was able to reproduce the same issue and the above solved it.

If your APK is outside the device (on your desktop), then below command would do it:

```
$ adb install -t hello.apk
```

Comment: You don't need to adb push and pm install, you can specify the -t switch just after the adb install command: adb install -t -r package.apk

Comment: no need to push the apk anymore adding -t works in adb install  works fine , for the full command check my answer below.

Comment: `adb push bin/hello.apk /tmp/` doesn't work for me, `adb push ./debug.apk /sdcard/temp/debug.apk` worked

Comment: `adb install -t app/build/outputs/apk/usUnitedStates/debug/app-usUnited-debug.apk` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. My app was a system app. Thus -f was needed.
`-f: Install package on the internal system memory.`

Comment: The `android:testOnly="true"`  is only set in the **build/intermediates/\*\*/AndroidManifest.xml** files. So I never added the flag in the first case.

Answer (score 111):

I had a similar problem with `Android Studio 3.0.0 Beta 7` and could not publish anymore to the play store.

As stated here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

> Note: The Run  button builds an APK with testOnly="true", which means
>   the APK can only be installed via adb (which Android Studio uses). If
>   you want a debuggable APK that people can install without adb, select
>   your debug variant and click Build > Build APK(s).

Same goes for release build, with `Android Studio 3` you need to go to `Build > Build APK(s)` to have a non testable release apk that you can submit to the store.

Comment: I suspect that right now (Oct/Nov 2017) this is the correct answer for most people who get here. Before AS 3, the APK produced by "Run" was installable even outside of AS, no it is not.

Comment: there's update and there's some more tweak.. took me a while to figure it out :/

Comment: Perfect. you saved my time. I had the same problem that I sent debug apk in outputs folder of project. I didn't know  that I should build it using BUILD APK

Answer (score 75):

Add `-t` install flag, as on the screenshot below:

[image: answer is in the red box]

Comment: The sample project I compile use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha7' and does not compile with a stable version, only adding -t as mentioned solved the issue for me.

Comment: Please explain what `-t` does.

Comment: in adb help, you will see install with -t means allow test packages

Comment: screen is launched via clicking Edit Configurations on the module dropdown menu - between Make and Run, Debug buttons at top of IDE : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html

Comment: @rmtheis From the command line you can run "adb" to see the flag meaning, which is: "-t: allow test packages"

Answer (score 56):

In my case this mistake was in unstable gradle version. Just use a stable version of gradle (not alpha, not even beta). And it was fixed for me

Comment: Saved the day! Changed the gradle version from 2.4.0-alpha3 to 2.3.0

Comment: The price of sticking to the bleeding edge... Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone confirm that setting android:testOnly="true" will fix it for unstable gradle versions too?

Answer (score 54):

After searching and browsing all day, the only one works is adding

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

to the **gradle.properties** file

Comment: Would I be able to release this build on play-store with key set as android.injected.testOnly = false or should I revert it back to "true" when I am uploading to play-store?

Comment: @prahlad-v-thej Pretty sure the opposite is true: Trying to upload an **testOnly** version to the Play-Store will fail.

My suspicion is that Google added **testOnly** so you don't accidentally upload a version meant for debugging and testing to the store.

Since I make clean builds before upload it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: This works, but then of course the app is more limited in terms of developing it... :(

Answer (score 28):

I agree with Elisey. I got this same error after opening my project in the 2.4 preview and then opening the same project in android studio 2.3

Fixed the issue by changing this line in build.gradle from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha5'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 28):

None of the previous post solve my issue. Here is what's happening with me:

I normally load the app from Android Studio by clicking on the "Run" button. When you do this, Android would create an app that's good for debug but not for install. If you try to install using:

```
adb install -r yourapk
```

you will get a message that says:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]

When this happens, you will need to rebuilt the apk by first clean the build, then select Build->Build APK. See the image below:

[image: build android apk]

This APK is ready to be installed either through adb install command or any other methods.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I was having trouble with the release build (faulty keystore) and wanted to distribute debug builds to my testers.

Comment: If you're using appium, you need to specify `"allowTestPackages": "true"` to your e2e scheme capabilities.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Can you please elaborate where to put allowTestPackages": "true"

Comment: @Girish You add it to your Appium driver config, like `config.allowTestPackages = true`. Note, this **only** pertains to end to end tests using Appium.

Answer (score 20):

Android studio 3.0 generates test only APK.

I have solved the issue by adding the "android:testOnly" property to android manifest's  tag.

```
 <application
    .....
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And then generated the APK by **Android studio3.0 menu:Build-->Build APK(s)**.

**More Info:**
https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Answer (score 16):

If you want to test the apk, just add the `-t` command line option.

Example command:

```
adb install -t .\app-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 16):

add this line to your ‘gradle.properties’

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

Comment: Thanks! This will fix spoon runner issue as well!

Comment: @nicklee Would I be able to release this build on play-store with key set as android.injected.testOnly = false or should I revert it back to "true" when I am uploading to play-store?

Answer (score 11):

In my case was by uploading an APK, that although it was signed with production certificate and was a release variant, was generated by the run play button from Android studio.
Problem solved after generating APK from Gradle or from Build APK menu option.

Comment: This started happening with Android Studio 3.0, and your suggestion fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Android 3.6.2 or later

Build >> Build/Bundle apk >> Build apk

[image]

Its working fine.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, using Android Studio 4.0, the below solved the issue;

Add to 'gradle.properties' file;

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```bash
adb install -t myapk.apk
```

Comment: it was useful for me , thank you

Comment: For the sake of clarity, the -t option allows the installation of an APK with test-only permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I see the accepted answer  but  you dont have to actually  push the apk and then run the  command on adb shell  direct  adb install with -t flag  actually works

> adb install -t "path to apk in ur  computer"

attaching a screenshot for reference
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest to solve this, without reverting to an older gradle version is to add the '-t' option in the run configurations (for pm install).

testOnly='false' had no effect whatsoever. The error is caused by the alpha version of gradle plugin that makes debug APK 'for test only purposes'. The -t option allows such APK to be installed. Setting it in run configuration makes it automatically install you APK as usual.

Answer (score 3):

My finding is as below. If I compile using the Android Studio UI, and the APK generated, I can't just

```
adb install <xxx.apk>
```

It will generate `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]`

I need to compile it using the gradle i.e. `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`. Then only the generated apk, then it can only be installed.

This is because the Android Studio UI Compile, only generate test apk for a particular device, while `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` command is the actual apk generation to be installed on all device (and upload to playstore)

Comment: Refers to https://medium.com/@elye.project/dont-publish-your-manually-compiled-apk-c8ce2bf7e6b4 to understand better of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's gonna be useful for anyone or not, but I got this error message, when I accidentally tried to build and install my project with test gradle plugin (`'gradle:2.4.0-alpha5'`) version in stable Android Studio version (`2.3`, not in `2.4 preview 5` version I'd downloaded and installed before).

When I realized my mistake, I launched preview Android Studio version and it built and installed my project without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html):

> Android Studio automatically adds this attribute when you click Run

So, to be able to install your apk with `adb install <path to apk file>` you need to assemble build from terminal: `./gradlew assembleDebug` and install with adb. Or just run `./gradlew installDebug` to build and install on the device simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Build your distribution .apk from Android Studio as follow

**Build --> Build Apk(s)**  (for unsigned build) 
**Build --> Generate Signed APK**  ( for signed build)

These option builds the APK with android:testOnly="false" option which allows you to install the APK expicitly into device by the commond.

adb install yourBuilT.apk

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is performing `Refresh all Gradle projects` from the `Gradle` toolbar from the right menu.

PFB the screenshot from Android Studio.

1. Select `Gradle` toolbar from the right menu.
2. Select the `Refresh` icon

This resolved the issue for me.

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

Comment: Thanks mate. It started after upgrading android gradle to 4.
Deploying the app directly from android studio works fine but not if using the terminal (adb install etc..)
After refreshing the gradle as you mentioned it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am sure Saurabh's answer will work for most other people, I did want to identify the extra steps I had to take in order to get my apk installed.

I tried pushing to the device with the following result:

```
? adb push AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk \tmp\
failed to copy 'AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk' to '\tmp\': Read-only file system
```

After looking around to change the filesystem RW permissions I ended up executing the following commands:

```
? adb shell
255|shell@android:/ $ su
shell@android:/ # mount -o remount,rw /
mount -o remount,rw /
```

I got this when I tried to push again:

```
? adb push AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk /tmp
failed to copy 'AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk' to '/tmp': Permission denied
```

I was able to  push to the sdcard:

```
? adb push AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk /sdcard/
3178 KB/s (99747 bytes in 0.030s)
```

At which point I was able to execute Saurabh's command:

```
shell@android:/ # pm install -t /sdcard/AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk
pm install -t /sdcard/AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk
        pkg: /sdcard/AppClient.TestOnly.App3.apk
Success
```

Comment: I should add that some of this may not be necessary for others.

Comment: Appreciate the extra effort!.

Answer (score 1):

For me it has worked execute the gradle task 'clean' (under :app, at Gradle pane, usually located at the right) and run again the project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried external project, with multiple apk.

The command from Studio,  looked like

```
adb install-multiple -r ....
```

Solution -

- select console
- aste command with `-t`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a less permanent solution then adding `android.injected.testOnly=false` to your **gradle.properties** file and you don't mind using the command line then the following two commands before installation will do:

```
rm -v **/build/**/AndroidManifest.xml
gradle build
```

For Windows users: delete all **AndroidManifest.xml** from all **build** directories. But not from the **src** directories so `DEL /S` is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and no answer helps.
At last, I find there's still an install in my Safe Folder(Or Secure folder depending phone brands), which had not been removed when Android uninstalled the ordinary install. Remove it and this issue fixed.
Hope this can help some guys else!

Answer (score 0):

Android studio from Iguana beta 1 stopped acepting generated apk file names with spaces.
If you are changing the apk name to include spaces, just remove them.
This is was a 2hr time waster without proper error messages or whatnot! Thanks google!

Answer (score -2):

first remove the unstable version:

`adb uninstall` *problematic-package-name*

; and then reinstall the apk.

Comment: No, that doesn't work — my test scripts do an uninstall automatically when the install fails.