# Android studio 3.0 you can not upload a test only apk

Tags: android

I just updated my old projects to as3.0 and builded and signed my app. After when I want to upload to google play:

"you can not upload a test only apk"

Any help?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GooglePlay error: cannot upload a test-only APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690118/googleplay-error-cannot-upload-a-test-only-apk)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a new feature from Android Studio 3.0. When you execute any gradle command by pressing 'Run' button in Android Studio, it adds `testOnly=true` flag to your manifest.

To eliminate this issue just execute `assembleRelease` from Gradle pane on the right side of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Evgenii Kanivets is right, but although you can use Build -> Generate Signed APK...

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up the build file to automatically sign your release, then you can also use

Build > Build APK

to configure the auto sign, the link is below.
(https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore)