# Failed to install APK with INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and the project I'm working on is using native code (C++).
The problem is that the APK that Android Studio creates must be installed with -t (test) flag.
 I looked at **Run** view of Android Studio, and it's using -t and -r flag. With the -r flag I don't have problem, but how do I build **Not** test APK?
I added android:testOnly="false" to the application tag in the Manifest, but it did not help.
Do you have any idea?
Does it happen because I'm using native code?
Can I add command to build.gradle to force it not to be test?

Comment: Just another stupid change by Google, see there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093554/android-studio-3-0-you-can-not-upload-a-test-only-apk

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use assembleDebug, not assembleRelease, but it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `Build` -> `Build APK(s)` and locate your `APK` file in your project->app->build->outputs->apk->debug->app-debug.apk. It will work for every android device