# "You cannot upload a test-only APK" when building by command line (assemble{Flavor}{Flavor}Release)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm aware of this question [Google Play error: cannot upload a test-only APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690118/google-play-error-cannot-upload-a-test-only-apk).

But I've built by `assemble{Flavor}{Flavor}Release` and Developer Console still rejected my build, while `assembleRelease` worked but took a long time because it has built all of the flavors. Only adding `android.injected.testOnly=false` to gradle.properties helps. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What key do you use for release flavour - debug key or release key?

Comment: Release key, debuggable to false, proguarded.

Answer (score 0):

Try install command with **-t** option

```
adb install -t /path/to/your/apk/app.apk
```

Comment: It's not about installation on the device, but generating the apk and sending it to Google play