# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY] Error while Installing APK

Tags: android

when i run the app, it shows a popup like the one on the first image and then when i click on ok it shows me the failure of the second image,

Image1

[image]

Image2

[image]
Any idea on what might cause this issue?

Comment: did you restart the android studio?

Comment: try uninstalling app from android device

Comment: i already try both but nothing change

Comment: This is a duplicate. There are already answers to this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only/42969467](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only/42969467)