# Android can't build release APK with gradle build tool 3.0.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got a problem with Android Studio 3 canary 2, generate APK file always be a TEST version and can't install on any devices unless using command "adb install **-t** apkname".

The error is **Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]**

Comment: This is on purpose. Works as designed.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it has not released yet.

Comment: I have the same problem with 3.0 beta 7 and I can't publish my APK to the store anymore because of my release APK being a 'test' APK. I don't understand @Henry 's answer. Could you provide more helpful insights? I use Realm which asked me to use some gradle features requiring studio 3.0 apparently. So now when I go back to 2.3 I can't build either...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB Install Fails With INSTALL\_FAILED\_TEST\_ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only)

Comment: @GabrielMorin see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969467/1796579

Comment: I actually found another solution in my case, I will suggest it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with `Android Studio 3.0.0 Beta 7`

As stated here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

> Note: The Run  button builds an APK with testOnly="true", which means
>   the APK can only be installed via adb (which Android Studio uses). If
>   you want a debuggable APK that people can install without adb, select
>   your debug variant and click Build > Build APK(s).

Same goes for release build, with `Android Studio 3` you need to go to `Build > Build APK(s)` to have a non testable release apk that you can submit to the store.