# How to overcome app not installed error when building from Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android, android-developer-api, android-debugging

For giving build for a debug Android app from Android Studio 3.0, it’s not installing in Mobile having Marshmallow and up (in Lollipop not tested).

I have used many solutions from Stack overflow but it’s still not working.

It’s always showing **App Not Installed** on mobile phone.

Comment: does your android mobile support marshmallow ? because when you are creating android app from studio it will ask for the target android version like if you choose android 4 success rate would be like 92+% that means your app what ever you build will run on 92+% devices .

Comment: does  your app is getting installed as apk in your mobile ?To do that you need to enable virtual debugging

Comment: Its android studio 3.0 and  compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion '26.0.2',minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: hi Tanmay I am not asking android studio configuration I am asking about your mobile android version.Does it support marshmellow?

Comment: yes  and virtual debugging option also on.

Comment: can you please enable log cat in android studio and start running the app if app is installed successfuly in your mobile then you can figureout the debug issue.Is your build getting success if you do runAs?Also for debuggin Ctrl+F9 is  short cut

Comment: When running  through usb its working but when i am sending the app link by uploading it to drive my debug apk its not installing.

Comment: hey bro you are totally confusing me how you can debug the app which is residing on google drive?With usb only you can debug apk  which will reside  in your actual mobile. I mean you run the code if the build is success from android studio.It will create an apk in your device r8.That you can debug but not on drive.Moreover you need to host your app if you want  remote debugging .I think you are getting confused with remote and local debugging

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for your support . I have to take the apk file from outputs of Android Studio and Upload it to my Google drive and Share the Shareablelink for testing. By doing that its giving me error like "App Not Installed".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157959/discussion-between-tanmay-sahoo-and-pradeep).

Comment: Hi Tanmay, Did you got any solution which worked for you, because I am facing same issue after upgrading android studio from 2.3 to 3.0

Comment: I just reinstalled the version 2.3.3.

Comment: Why don't you use Alpha release channels using the Google Play Console?
You just need to become a tester of your app and you can download it from everywhere, like an app on the Play Store.
I don't think you can just install the apk from Google Drive and expect it's working.

Comment: @TanmaySahoo what is the message reported?, did you see a dialog reporting the problem?

Comment: Hi Tanmay, I have got the same problem like you, App is installing while connecting via USB to mobile, but while sending .apk file to others it saying "App not Installed"(both debug and release).I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow but none worked for me.Can you please help me on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230952/app-not-installed-when-upgraded-to-android-p?noredirect=1#comment85466788_49230952

Comment: I suggest trying this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55489016/452487

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855995/1318946

Answer (score 8):

Well the original question doesn´t have enough information, but we can have some info getting some comments:

> - Android studio 3.0 and compileSdkVersion 26, buildToolsVersion '26.0.2',minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 26
> - virtual debugging option also on.
> - I am facing same issue after upgrading android studio from 2.3 to 3.0

Ok the message `"App Not Installed"` will refer to multiple causes, and please returning to Android Studio 2.3. from 3.0 is not an option!

When we upgrade from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0  we can find some configuration issues caused mainly by the support libraries, that will cause that our application could not be installed.

To avoid this problem we need to invalidate cache in Android Studio 3.0+ and the problem will be solved.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Please try this option.

Comment: agree with @Jorgesys, happen to me when using another pc, clean, rebuild, and restart solve problem

Comment: I have to sign in to up vote your solution. Work for me after a whole day of trying other solutions. (Android Studio 3.3.1)

Answer (score 5):

First try to generate the debug apk by below steps:

1. Goto Run
2. Edit Configurations
3. select + icon on the left side
4. Select Gradle
5. Click the Configuration tab if it is not selected in the right side
6. In Gradle project add your app as  a gradle project
7. From the tasks select/set "assemble"
8. Press ok

Now run that configuration.
you will have the debug apk ready in build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk.
Now install that apk in any device. It should work.

Comment: This should have been the accepted Answer.

Answer (score 3):

As of Android Studio 3 the Run-Button builds test-only apks. [See documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/)

> Note: The Run  button builds an APK with testOnly="true", which means the APK can only be installed via adb (which Android Studio uses). If you want a debuggable APK that people can install without adb, select your debug variant and click Build > Build APK(s).

This solved my issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46661987/7756799

Comment: For me this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers solved the issue. The build and install was going fine when it's triggered from android studio with a device connected to the computer or with an emulator, the only issue was when **sending the apk via email or hockey app**.

How I could fix it (and this might not be the solution for everybody), I enabled the multidex support by adding this to the default config:

```
// Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
```

PS: Usually Android Studio build would fail if the multidex support has to be enabled, in this new version this didn't happen, but my Jenkins build was broken and this is how I could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh this is exactly we have to do:

1. Go to Build
2. Build Apk
3. Locate Apk

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio goto build menu and then Build Aps(s). Its work fine for me.

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138086).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 type of APK Signature #1 JAR signature (aka v1) and #2full APK sign (aka v2): Not all the devices recognize it ,so make sure you anable both V1 and V2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case my debug apk worked fine but when I tried to install Signed apk then following error shows

**"APP not Installed"**

then I haved added

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in gradle fine then its work fine

Comment: I dont think there is a logical reason why this should work.

Answer (score -2):

**Android Studio -> Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s) -> Reinstall new APK on mobile phone**

[image: Build Unsigned App]