# Debugging Android application: installing apk gives "app not installed"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am using androidx packages in my project. Today, I am suddenly facing issues when installing the application on my device.

I use the following:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha16'
```

in app gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0'
```

Now, when I am creating build and run on device, it works perfectly fine!

When I create build from Build bundle/apk and copy that APK in mobile and install it, it is giving error as "**App not installed**".
Note:

- There is not any already installed application on device.
- There are no multiple user case on device.
- This error is not coming on signed apk but it is on ***debug apk*** as well.
- This project is flavor based and package name is different for each flavor.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47705238/5050924) ?

Comment: Yes, that is not an issue, it is already tried,

Comment: If I create new sample project using Android studio 3.2 Canary 16 and convert it to AndroidX, build apk from Build -> Build bundle -> apk and copy that in device, it gives error as: “App not installed”