# Android studio 3.2 canary 16 build issue

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Android studio version: 3.2 canary 16
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27

I have just create one default android project from android studio as: New project -> choose min and max sdk version -> blank activity -> ready

Build that project, create build apk from Build -> Build bundle/apks -> build apk -> copy that apk on device and install, works fine!

Now, from refactor option -> refactor to AndroidX
done same step again:  from Build -> Build bundle/apks -> build apk -> copy that apk on device and install -> giving error as : "**App not installed**"

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use release apk  for test case.

Comment: Same issue with release apk as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: same asked perviously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611548/debugable-andorid-application-installation-gives-app-not-installed