# After uninstall app on device flutter run not work

Tags: flutter, run-app

I'm using vs code for building my flutter app.
But after uninstall debug app on my device, 'flutter run' command not working properly and stop in installing status.
Please help me.
Thanks.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on RNE L21 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                      ۱۱٫۷s
Resolving dependencies...                                   ۱۴٫۹s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         ۱۰۱٫۷s
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...                  ۶٫۱s
```

Comment: This apk file size is 32mb 

Comment: Did you do a flutter clean before flutter run?

Comment: yes, i solved this problem with copy debug app on device and install it, after this, flutter debug worked properly.
and also when i want to delete app on my devise, i using settings->app->"uninstall for all users"

Comment: Only to add that in my LG G6 (and maybe in other mobiles from other companys) exist the "App Trash", where the uninstalled apps stays for 24/48 extra hours. If our developed app is there, 'flutter run' also doesn't works.

Answer (score 10):

It seems like when you uninstall the flutter application, though it is no longer available on the phone It is not deleted properly(Only in the flutter case). Therefore to fix this. you can run `adb` and uninstall from the package. Here is a step-by-step procedure.
If you are in windows:
**Step 1**. Open your SDK path in command prompt
eg.
`C:\Users\kharag\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

**Step 2**. Search your app package name from the flutter app (It will be in AndroidManifest.xml)
eg.
`com.mycodingchannel.icttapp`
**Step 3**. Now uninstall your app by running the command:

```
adb uninstall com.mycodingchannel.icttapp
```

That's all, Now run your app and it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, copied .apk file on device and installed it from there, after that debugger worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Once you see Built/..... in termial. The apk has been created. Now if the installing fails/takes long time. Go to [app folder\app\outputs\apk]

Copy the app.apk/debug.apk any other file to your device and install it.
Now once you re-run it will work fine.

If that doesn't work flutter clean+flutter pub get. Follow the above step.