# Cant run or debug on a Mobile phone with flutter application

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, apk

I am having an issue of debugging and running the application on the mobile phone (Nokia 7), but the console shows that they are installing the app, but am seeing nothing. The issue started yesterday, and I thought it was the storage issue but it wasn't. *I tested this by running a native android(kotlin) application and it worked in Android studio*.  This is the console message I get

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 7 plus in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
```

But the app doesn't launch on my end.

**EDIT**

After running `flutter run -v`, I get the following logs :

```
[  +27 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +56 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 18cd7a3601bcffb36fdf2f679f763b5e827c2e8e
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.6-0-g18cd7a3601
[   +9 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/beta
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +34 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +83 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +35 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] beta
[  +93 ms] executing: C:\Users\Huxy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\Huxy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           B2NGAA9832322729       device product:Onyx_00WW model:Nokia_7_plus device:B2N_sprout transport_id:36
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:14
[  +14 ms] More than one device connected; please specify a device with the '-d <deviceId>' flag, or use '-d all' to act on all devices.
[   +5 ms] C:\Users\Huxy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s B2NGAA9832322729 shell getprop
[  +59 ms] ro.hardware = qcom
[   +2 ms] C:\Users\Huxy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +37 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +18 ms] Nokia 7 plus              • B2NGAA9832322729 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
[   +4 ms] Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554    • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
[        ] Chrome                    • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 81.0.4044.122
[        ] Web Server                • web-server       • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
[   +8 ms] "flutter run" took 299ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:289:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:590:11)
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:515:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
#10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:505:20)
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:413:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:364:19)
#20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:250:18)
#24     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:63:22)
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12)
#29     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#30     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
#31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#33     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#34     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#35     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
#36     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64:24)
#37     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#38     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:65:9)
#39     main (file:///C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#40     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#41     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

Comment: Try `flutter run -v` and post the outputs

Comment: @iKeepChangingName, checkout the logs I get, I have updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809421/flutter-is-not-able-to-install-the-apk-into-the-real-device-suddenly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter is not able to install the apk into the real device suddenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809421/flutter-is-not-able-to-install-the-apk-into-the-real-device-suddenly)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue and it was caused by a conflicting (same) app with the same package name that's still installed on the device. I uninstalled the app from the device's Settings and I was able to finally install the app on the device.