# flutter debug APK not installing on mobile

Tags: flutter

Am not able to install the APK in my mobile generated by gradle. it's working fine on an emulator but when I try to install on my mobile its starts installing and in the middle, it gives the error APK not installed. Am running android 10. Paths from where I picked the debug APKs are as follow.

```
<project>/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
<project>/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app.apk
<project>/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
```

Comment: Check if USB debugging is enabled in your device

Comment: @AdithyaShetty I tried this also. Actually am not debugging the app I just want to install it on my mobile to see if it's working properly on different mobiles as expected. I don't want to upload it on the store yet so I think i don't need a release apk with a signed certificate I just wanted to share the apk with client so that he can see how its working

Comment: You mean to say you have a USB connection to the device and you run the app form the  IDE/editor and it does not install the app in your phone?

Comment: @AdithyaShetty there is no connection btw pc and mobile it's just an APK shared through BlueTooth to my device now I am trying to install it.

Comment: I don't know why it is installing if install from unknow Sources is turned on. I have a way around, connect your phone with your PC run the APP from the editor, this will install the app on your phone as it does on an emulator, then stop running form the editor /ide, you should see the app installed in your phone.

Comment: @AdithyaShettyokay I ll try this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855995/1318946

Answer (score 0):

It seems your apk does not have certificate yet.
you cant install it just like that. you can either certify it [build release android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

or set your phone to install app form unknown source. in app settings or security settings

Comment: my settings allow the apps to be installed from an unknown source but still, I can't

Comment: He is not trying to release it he is trying to debug it on a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to manually install the app-debug.apk, you should rather consider generating app-release.apk but if you can't debug the app, then you might considering opening up your developer options.

Comment: well me developers option is already open what can I do next? actually this is my first time creating an app.