# App not installed after upgrading to Android - P

Tags: android, build, android-9.0-pie

App is installing while connecting via USB to mobile, but while sending .apk file to others it saying "App not Installed"(both debug and release).I have tried different solutions from stackoverflow but none worked for me.

1.How to overcome app not installed error when building from Android Studio 3.0?

2.Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"

3.Android Studio 3.0 Unsigned Apk Not Installing

Below is my build.gradle(app level)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 51
        versionName "1.51"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    lintOptions{
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }

}
```

Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: increase your `targetSdkVersion 26` to `targetSdkVersion 27` or whatever for `android P`

Comment: Remove `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'` line.

Comment: Check this thing where you are installing that .apk file :-   Settings -> Security -> Unknown Source should be checked . If it's checked then clean and rebuild the project then build apk

Comment: hi Kuldip, Aziibekian, Abhinav I have tried above solutions specified unfortunetely none worked me.Thanks for your response guys.Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6):

You can override `testOnly` flag adding following line to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

Answer (score 4):

Android P preview SDK is a preview and you should not be distributing APKs built with it. Use a non-preview SDK for compiling APKs that are meant for other people to use.

Technically, the installation limitation is that the APKs have `testOnly` flag set to true. To work around that, see [ADB Install Fails With INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only)

Comment: Hi laalto, Thanks for your response. I need to build both debug and release builds.will both(debug and release) builds will work if I add android:testOnly="true" in Manifest file ?Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I don't think you can override the testonly flag set by P preview SDK. Just don't use a preview SDK that widely yet.

Comment: Hi, when I degrade compileSdkVersion 26, Project not building showing cornerRadiusError in values.xml.I cannot able to understand.Please help me on this.

Comment: Error:(9, 5) error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found. when I degrade to compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: Guess: you have `+` dynamic dependencies to support libraries and are getting too new a version. Hardcode your dependency versions.

Comment: I didn't get you laalto.Sorry can you please explain ?

Comment: Post a new question with that particular issue. Include your build.gradle `dependencies`

Comment: Hi laalto, Can you please check the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249713/cannot-able-to-build-the-project-after-upgrading-to-android-p.Please help me on this.

Comment: Added Dependencies to this Link,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249713/cannot-able-to-build-the-project-after-upgrading-to-android-p