# 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android' No resource identifier found for attribute

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I did not find any solution for this issue, 
actually error is in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"**

Comment: anyone have the solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266035/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-appcomponentfactory-in-package-and)

Answer (score 4):

Just install this plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but would you mind explaining briefly why or pointing me in the right direction? I seem to be spending far too much of my time chasing issues like this.

I'm building an ionic-v3 project and had just done a fresh npm install and removed and recreated my cordova android platform.

I set my version to 26.+ based on my setup but not sure whether that was a good idea or not.

Comment: well answer you  save my day

Comment: how can I Install this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use cordova android@8.0.0
Follow these steps.

• Run:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

• Run:

```
ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0
```

• Run:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
```

• Run:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

with this steps your build will work again

Comment: Probably not a good idea to go for an old version. You will have a hard time if you want to release to play store.