# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Here's my ionic info

> √ Gathering environment info - done!
>
> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1
>   (C:\Users\DRAGONBALL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic
>   Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
>
> Cordova:
>
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)    Cordova
>   Platforms     : android 6.2.3    Cordova Plugins       : no
>   whitelisted plugins (12 plugins total)
>
> System:
>
> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5 (D:\Backupdata\Android\sdk)    NodeJS
>   : v8.9.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm               :
>   6.9.0    OS                : Windows 7

I have tried solutions mentioned in the [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266035/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-appcomponentfactory-in-package-and) but nothing works.

HEre is the Manifest from build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.omkarfatale.predictor"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:versionCode="10900"
android:versionName="1.9" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.omkarfatale.predictor.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <!--
         FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
         but set to not exported to explicitly avoid allowing another app to call it.
    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.omkarfatale.predictor.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are using some resource the does't exist in your project .

Comment: Actually, I really don't know much about this. What resource you are talking about?