# failed linking references after update of gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I got this error after update my Gradle (I have also added maven{jitpack.io} and geofirestore dependencies at the same of updating Gradle) :

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1169: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1170: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Paul\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\74062dcec80f00402d5904d26f22db6e\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.how2ride.how2ride\
        -0\
        apk\
        -c\
        en,fr\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Paul\AndroidStudioProjects\How2Ride2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

How can I solve this?

Here my Project build gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my Module build gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.how2ride.how2ride"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android:v1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have the last version of android studio and my project worked perfectly before upgrading my gradle...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Change the compileSdkVersion to:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

These attributes were added in this version. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#dialogCornerRadius), [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#ttcIndex)

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I had same problem with compileSdkVersion 27 and gragdle version: 3.1.4, is this a bug in gradle?

Comment: @MaksimNovikov I'm not sure. is your `buildToolsVersion` >= 28.00?

Comment: It resolves the issue but I get the error related to targetSdkVersion https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553352/971355

Not sure how to fix both errors...

Answer (score 9):

Downgrade your gradle version to 3.1.4 i.e classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

Comment: This worked for me: R.java was not found anymore after updating to Gradle version 3.3.0. Downgrading to 3.2.1 solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade gradle on 3.1.4 . 
Check for your **build.gradle**(Modele:App) file:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

The project was built :)

Answer (score 5):

check for your **graddle-wrapper.properties** file

```
Sun Jul 08 23:40:54 KST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

check the last line the gradle version file url

Answer (score 3):

try this code in this build.gradle

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your classpath to the current build gradle and sync your project.There seems to be an issue with Android studio version 3.2. When prompted to update gradle also update the classpath values.

Answer (score 2):

was facing this issue today after updating to the new gradle 3.0.1 to 3.2.0 for my case i deleted the ids.xml file in values folder (it was useless in the project) work for me