# Android apk Installation failed. Installation package error, unable to install

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am developing an app, if I run from android studio in to my device, it is running absolutely fine. If I put my apk into google drive and share with others, it is showing error `("Android apk Installation failed. Installation package error, unable to install.")` when they try to install the app. It's not a signed apk. It's still in prototype phase (debug mode).

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266270/4406346

Comment: Before install the APK, make sure to uninstall any older version of same application.

Comment: @FaridHaq, Yes i have done that.

Comment: @IffatFatima It's still in debug mode. I don't have a signed key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed)

Comment: make sure the apk was generated in release mode

Comment: Make sure minimum SDK version is less or equal to the device android version in which you are installing the app

Comment: @Firu Its not a signed apk . It's just in prototype phase. Yes i have kept minimum SDK version less only than the device. I kept it 17 and device is 5.1 android version.

Comment: @Ogbe It's in prototype phase. So its  in debug phase only.

Comment: you should generate a release apk if you want to install it outside your development environment

Comment: As @Ogbe suggested you need to generate signed APK if you want to install it outside the dev environment. Or else disable Instant Run in Android Studio and re-build the project and try to install debug APK. But I don't think this procedure works in recent versions of Android Studio IDE.

Comment: @Ogbe Thanks for the answer. i did that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem I faced. Some solutions i tried :

First I tried with generating a signed release apk. Again here I faced same issue working fine when ran from android studio but getting error ("Android apk Installation failed. Installation package error, unable to install." / "app not installed." depending on the device ) , when tried to install app from google drive.

I checked installing app from command line using command " adb install app-release.apk ". Then I got the error :

> app-release.apk: 1 file pushed. 4.3 MB/s (1246134 bytes in 0.275s)
>     pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-release.apk Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]

This is the link for the above issue
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only)

And the solution for this issue was in same link. The solution finally worked for me was

> android.injected.testOnly=false

This line we need to add in gradle.properties file.