# Cannot run install apk on physical device but installed on emulater

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk

I'm new to Android studio and app development but I made a simple app which seems to install and work fine when run from Android studio. I have two emulators, stock one created from Android studio and VS Android Emulator. The app installs and runs when run from the studio but doesn't when I manually drag and drop to install on VS Android Emulator. It rather give this error:

```
Performing Push Install
C:\Users\EDON\AndroidStudioProjects\Starbuzz2\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 0.2 MB/s (2035792 bytes in 10.550s)
WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]
```

When I installed on a physical device too, I got `App Not Installed` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB Install Fails With INSTALL\_FAILED\_TEST\_ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only)

Comment: See also https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: Did you enable debug mode on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

So after doing many searches, I found out I had to Sign the app. It got installed on both the emulator and the physical device after signing the app in Android studio...thank you all...