# Xamarin Android install flags

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm building an Xamarin android admin app meaning that the app will be the device admin but in order to be able to uninstall the app while developing I need to add to the android manifest `android:testOnly="true"` 
but then it fails at deployment I get the following error

```
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]
```

and to avoid that error I need to pass an install flag with adb as written this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274296/adb-install-fails-with-install-failed-test-only)

how do I do that in VS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please archive your application then export the xxx.apk file. Note: when you archive your application, please notice following settings.

1. **unselect** following settings
   [image]
2. **select** following settings.
   [image]

For example, I archive my application to root path of `F` desk like following screenshot.

[image]

Then, open the adb command to click the icon like following screenshot.

[image]

Enter the `F:` in the adb console. Then enter the `adb install -t -r com.companyname.app25.apk` like following screenshot(please make sure your android emulator is running).

[image]

In the end, you will found your apk file was installed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. but how do I attach it to the debugger?

Comment: Based on my research, If you use this way to install your APK by `ADB`, you cannot debug it by VS, you have to see logs in the logcat. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept this answer(click the✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: I can't say its answered  because the real answer is that you cannot pass install flags when  deploying with VS while debugging. the question was not how to archive the application and install it via adb

Comment: Ok. If used this way, it can achieve it.